# How to create dual control java keystore file

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, private-key, jce

Want to create java key-store file and create secret key using multiple users/user passwords.

generally we can create key-store file in this way,

```
keytool -genseckey -keystore <filename>.jceks -storetype jceks -storepass <passwrod> -keyalg AES -keysize 256 -alias <alias name> -keypass <key password>
```

here, only one person has access to key-store file and keys, also that person can access that file without getting any others support. So only one have full permission.

Requirement is to distribute this permissions within 2 or 3 peoples.

Is there any way to overcome this problem in java key-store(jceks) file ?

Comment: Each user should have his own keystore.

Answer (score 0):

I try to find solution in various ways. Finally I find out this https://github.com/evanx/vellum/wiki/DualControl
. Could get a solution from this source.